# Is there a way to destroy an entire cachegroup thats similar to destroying a cache?

Tags: ignite

When you call destroy on a standard, standalone cache in ignite it seems that the underlying files are removed entirely and quickly and there is not significant cost to the operation.

Removing a cache from a large cache group however uses significant resources as it has to iterate over the partitions and remove data from just that singular cache, while leaving other caches in that cache group untouched. We find ourselves wanting to delete the entire cache group far more often than just individual caches from that group due how we logically group our data. I've tried calling the cache.destroy() method in the java library, as well as using the control script cache destroy method, and both return successfully as if the operation had been completed when provided with the cacheGroup name, however there is no change to any underlying resources on the nodes or to the cacheGroup itself.